# Why Gnome desktop services work simultaneously with Unity desktop?  

Tags: unity, unity-2d

After I log into unity-2d i see gnome panel and some other services working along side with unity services and I cannot get rid of these services.

Besides, unity panel gets locked sometimes and i have to logout and login. Why?

Comment: Does this still happen? This was an old problem early in the alphas.

Answer (score 1):

May be this can fix,

get your terminal and type this:
"killall unity"

and remove unity in the startup services or whatever its called.